# How to prove that Hurwitz matrix is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on one linear algebra question: Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and its all eigenvalues have negative real parts (this matrix is called Hurwitz matrix. How to prove that matrix is invertible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the eigenvalues are $0$, so the equation $Ax=0$ has no non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Sorry. why can we say $\det(A)\neq 0$ (Ax=0 has trivial solution) from the fact that all eigenvalues are not 0?

Comment: If there exists a vector $x \neq 0$ such that $Ax = 0 = 0x$ then $0$ is an eigenvalue with that $x$ as an eigenvector.